# Почему здесь не просто удаляется нулевой элемент вектора, а еще и заменяется значение второго?

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, задание-на-собеседовании

Почему в данном коде, после строки `v.erase(v.begin());` не просто удаляется нулевой элемент вектора, а еще и заменяется значение второго.

```
class A
{
public:
    int* p;

    A() : p() {}

    A(int _) : p(new int(_)) {}

    A(const A& a) {
        p = new int(*a.p);
    }

    virtual ~A() {
        delete p;
    }
};

void dump(const A& a)
{
    std::cout << *a.p << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> v;
    v.push_back(A(1));
    v.push_back(A(2));
    v.push_back(A(3));
    
    v.erase(v.begin());

    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), dump);

    
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод

```
2
-2054136144
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вообще говоря, для поддержки всех операций вектор требует, чтобы тип был как *[CopyConstructable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyConstructible)*, так и **[*CopyAssignable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyAssignable)**, т.е. в нём применяется `operator=()`, а т.к. ты нарушил [правило трёх](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%82%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85_(C%2B%2B)), то `operator=()` по умолчанию делает глупость просто копируя указатель. Надо просто явно его определить:

```
A& operator=(const A& a) {
    delete p;
    p = new int(*a.p);
    return *this;        
}
```

Comment: А освободить память, чтоб утечек не было?...

Comment: уже поправил =)... а ты не-константу вернул...

Comment: А я и не собираюсь возвращать константу. Мало ли что я захочу делать с этим присвоенным элементом? Типа, `(a=b).increaseValue();` Так что на минус это не тянет :)

Comment: @Harry, минус не мой, если что... кому-то армейская байка, видать не понравилась...

Comment: Грустные воспоминания отправленного в армию после неуспешной сессии :)

Comment: кстати про `const` я был не прав.... вообще говоря, *CopyAssignable* требует неконстантной ссылки...

Answer (score 3):

Представим себе строй солдат - значений в векторе.

Ррррассчитайсь!

Первый-второй-третий-...

Первого враги выводят и расстреливают. Ну, или начальство награждает и демобилизует. Неважно! Важно, что в строю его больше нет...

Ррррассчитайсь!

Первый-второй-третий-...

И кто теперь крикнет "первый"?

Только вот строй такой, что никто не умеет правильно делать шаг влево :) - нет оператора присваивания... Вот они при попытке сомкнуть строй просто падают. А поскольку освобождение места в строю сопровождается освобождением памяти - то проблемы поверхностного копирования становятся слишком глубокими :)

Вопросов больше нет?

Допишите в класс вот такой оператор -

```
A& operator=(const A& a) {
    cout << "===\n";
    delete p;
    p = new int(*a.p);
    return *this;
}
```

(вывод - чтоб вы видели, когда он вызывается) и посмотрите на [результат](https://ideone.com/wnOCUK).